# Recent movie, woman is trapped in a medical pod (stasis pod?) and is trying everything to convince its AI to let her out

Tags: story-identification, movie, artificial-intelligence

Pretty sure most of the movie is filmed of the woman in a pod. (Size of a coffin) It is high tech, looks like a stasis pod or medical pod with a heads up display she uses to interface with the pod. She wakes up inside it, and spends most of the movie lying on her back interacting with an AI? or computer voice as she tries trying to hack it to get it to open up and let her out.

Something (maybe her trying to hack it?) damaged the pod and her oxygen is running out. (Maybe it was damaged before and the computer woke her up to inform her.)

She might also be having flashbacks to before she entered the pod (childhood?) I think she has amnesia and cant remember who she is.

It is probably less than 10 years old, in English. Except for her and the computer voice  and a man whom she finally gets in contact with, there is no one else shown (Not 100% sure if there were any flashbacks).

It's possible it was not a movie, but an episode of a Twilight Zone or Outer Limits type show.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's [*Oxygen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_(2021_film)) (2021).

Despite several Google searches and looking at Google images for pictures from the movie, I found it doing a search on YouTube.

From IMDB.com:

> Having no recollection of how she ended up there, Liz Hansen wakes up from her deep hypnosis in an air-sealed cryogenic unit the size of a coffin. With the oxygen resources steadily depleting, Liz must remain composed to piece together her fragmented memories and reconstruct her opaque identity with the help of M.I.L.O., the pod's state-of-the-art A.I. However, trapped Liz can't move, she can't get out, and her oxygen levels can only last ninety short minutes. Does Liz have a fighting chance of surviving? Is there an escape from this claustrophobic nightmare?

Comment: I was surprised at how much I liked this movie. I think the actress sold it really well. Everything hinges on her.

Comment: Funny fact: In Italy, they used the French title, *Oxygène*, instead of using the English title which is normally used when they do not translate the title in Italian.

Comment: @apaderno Apparently it IS a French movie originally Oxygène.  I guess(?) they dubbed and renamed it Oxygen for the USA release.

Comment: @NJohnny Yes, but in Italy we do not usually use French titles; we use Italian or English titles. Well, sometimes it's a type of English we only use. ;-)